# Get PackageName when Intent.CreateChooser invoked in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I had written an Intent that is used to share some text to the chosen app, I want to get the package name of that particular chosen app.

```
public void ShareText(string text)
        {
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);
            sharingIntent.SetType("text/plain");
            sharingIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, text);
            StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"),555);
        }
```

I got null in OnActivityResult

```
    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
    if(requestCode == 555)
       {
          // data is null
       }
    }
```

How do I get this?

As we can see this in Chrome mobile app.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Intent is null
>
> I want to get the package name of that particular chosen app.

It is totally dependent upon the selection that the user made and if that selection provides any return `Intent`.

So, for example, the app is sharing some plain text and the user chooses:

- `Clipboard`

  - The returned intent would be `null`
- `Google Drive`

  - The returned intent would contain the URI from GDrive:

    - i.e. com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.legacy.XXXXXX
- `Google Mail`

  - The returned is null

etc...

Comment: I shared with WhatsApp and it returns null. `Intent.CreateChooser` is appearing slow, I want to fetch the app package name so that I allow user to share with that app. We can see this in Chrome browser mobile app.

Comment: @Amit If the native Android app does not provide any return intent information then there is nothing you can do, that is just the way `Intent.CreateChooser` works. If you have to obtain installed package names for Intent/mime types, this is not the way to do it, you would need to build your own routine and chooser.

Comment: If there any alternative way to achieve this, please share some link or reference

Comment: @Amit You can use `PackageManager.ResolveActivity` to obtain a list of installed package names that can handle a particular `Intent`.

Comment: @SushiiHangover I had attached a snapshot.